# Can the Mann-Whitney U test be used for related data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am comparing the annual profit margins of a set of 15 restaurants before and after they gained a "Michelin Star".

I have multiple non-uniform numbers of profit margins for each restaurant before and after they gained a star i.e. 3 profit margins before: 5 after; 2 profit margins before: 4 after etc. I have 57 Profit Margins recorded before these restaurants gained a Michelin Star and 55 after they gained a Nimchelin Star.

The Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test is not appropriate for my data, as I am comparing multiple results from each participant (restaurant). Therefore a "case by case" test does not seem suitable.

The Mann Whitney U Test would work well, apart from the data is related.

Therefore, can the Mann Whitney U Test still be used to test significant difference for my data?

If not, which test could I alternatively use?